# How does Python mimic the behavior of Perl multi-level hash chain extraction and concatenation

Tags: python, perl, dictionary, hash

I've always use Perl hash reference tricks to deal with tree structures.
This time, I have to do it in Python that I am not really familiar with.
For example, in the following code. I create a hash chain and cut it to half. Then I concatenate one piece to another hash chain.

```
my $hashRoot->{'1'}->{'2'}->{'C'}->{'D'} = 'val';
my $subHash = $hashRoot->{'1'}->{'2'};             #Extract the Last 2 Level of Chain
my $anotherHashRoot->{'A'}->{'B'} = $subHash;      #Concatenate to another Hash Chain

say '$hashRoot';
say Dump $hashRoot;
say '$subHash';
say Dump $subHash;
say '$anotherHashRoot';
say Dump $anotherHashRoot;
```

Above code generates output as following:

```
$hashRoot
---
1:
  2:
    C:
      D: val

$subHash
---
C:
  D: val

$anotherHashRoot
---
A:
  B:
    C:
      D: val
```

In short, I am searching a Pythonic way to cut/insert/copy a hash(dict) chain as in Perl (or in C). Does anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to declare a dictionary in Python. First of all, you can do it straight-forward, in this case:

```
>>> your_dict = {1: {2: {'C': {'D': 'val'}}}}
>>> print(your_dict)
{1: {2: {'C': {'D': 'val'}}}}
>>> sub_dict = your_dict[1][2]
>>> print(sub_dict)
{'C': {'D': 'val'}}
>>> new_dict = {'A': {'B': sub_list}}
>>> print(new_dict)
{'A': {'B': {'C': {'D': 'val'}}}}
```

This particular case is not perfectly suitable for using generator expressions, but it's also possible to use [them](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to build a dict. And, of course, you can create a dictionary in a `for-loop`.

You may be also interested in additional data-types in python, such as: [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

If you want to understand how `dict` objects work, it's a good idea to read this [spec](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Some important parts:

> `object.__len__(self)`
>   Called to implement the built-in function len().
>   Should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0. Also, an
>   object that doesn’t define a `__nonzero__()` method and whose `__len__()`
>   method returns zero is considered to be false in a Boolean context.
>
> `object.__getitem__(self, key)`
>   Called to implement evaluation of
>   self[key]. For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers
>   and slice objects. Note that the special interpretation of negative
>   indexes (if the class wishes to emulate a sequence type) is up to the
>   `__getitem__()` method. If key is of an inappropriate type, TypeError may be raised; if of a value outside the set of indexes for the
>   sequence (after any special interpretation of negative values),
>   IndexError should be raised. For mapping types, if key is missing (not
>   in the container), KeyError should be raised.
>
> `object.__missing__(self, key)`
>   Called by `dict.__getitem__()` to
>   implement self[key] for dict subclasses when key is not in the
>   dictionary.